# Stats problem for a chemistry calclulation

Tags: statistics

A class measures the density of something and the total class data is 12.7, 11.2, 10.3, 11.5, 11.4, 11.4, 10.9, 11.3, 11.1, it asks me to find the average which is (101.8)/9 which to the correct number of sig figs is 11.31. Now its asks me to find the percentage error of the class' average. They have it being (11.31-11.3)/11.3 where 11.31 is the estimate and 11.3 is the "exact". I don't get why 11.3 is the exact, how are they figuring that 11.3 is the "exact" value??

Comment: Perhaps they are simply telling you that $11.3$ is the exact value.  You would have to give the full wording of the question.

Comment: that's the thing is it doesn't say anywhere that 11.3 is the "exact" but I'm thinking it might be that the average was 11.31 and that means it's either 11.30 or 11.32 and in the data set there is a measurement of 11.3.

Comment: $11.3$ is the median of the class data